# Windows activity and register

Tags: regedit, register

How can I track changes a prog or game do in windows, for instance I want to keep track of changing in files done by a game such as Assassins creed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several. I use [process monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and (freeware) for file and registry changes (it uses to be separate tools called FileMon on RegMon now all packed into one tool). Most of the times those two "monitors" are enough to see all the relevant changes. Depends on what exactly you want to monitor.

But "be warned", there is some manual labour involved creating the necessary filters. At the very least you need to identify all the processes belonging to Assassins Creed, otherwise you will see all changes done by all processes.

Comment: Process monitor you mean a program or process monitor built-in task manager of windows?

Comment: @abdelrahman I put a link in my anser now

Comment: @abdelrahman glad I could help, feel free to accept the [accept](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) the answer (of course only if it actually solves your problem)

Comment: I will try it first to make sure it hits the target

Comment: @abdelrahman good luck!

Answer (score 1):

- As mentioned, [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), a free tool from Microsoft (Sysinternals), shows what processes do, *in great detail*.
- [DiskMonitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/diskmon), another free Sysinternals tool, monitors any and all changes to the disk.
- [RegistryChangesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html), a free application from Nirsoft, is ideal for showing changes an application makes to the Registry, and most succinct: it compares a snapshot of the Registry made *before* the game runs with one made afterward, so you can isolate *changes*.

Comment: Not really sure how DiskMonitor should help here but RegistryChangesView sounds interesting. How would you differentiate which changes were made by "the game" and which were made were made by other processes?

Comment: Differential analysis; i.e., run it with and without game.

Comment: Assuming the system behaves "the same", but that's a topic for a different time ;) I'm just wondering (not for this question but for myself) since the RegMon-Part shows me all the changes as well, is there s.th. I can get from RegistryChangesView which I can not get from RegMon? Maybe the previous value (I think RegMon only shows me the current one), anything else?